# Build a clickable URL passing more than 1 parameter in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to build a clickable URL inside my lightning component as given below

```
<a aura:id="child321" 
   href="{!'/apex/viewAllRegionsVerticalHierarchyCR?id='+v.acco‌​untId1+'&Region='+it‌​em.key}"
>
   <h3>
      View all<br/>
      {!item.value} Children<br/>
      Of {!item.key} Region
   </h3>
</a>
```

But upon saving given ParseError is coming because of & character.I tried using escape character but with no avail.
--The reference to entity "Region" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: Can you provide your code? It will be easier to debug then

Comment: Sorry I missed to give the desired URL :`enter code here`

Comment: Sorry I missed to give the desired URL :`<a aura:id="child321" href="{!'/apex/viewAllRegionsVerticalHierarchyCR?id='+v.accountId1+'&Region='+item.key}">
<h3>View all<br/>{!item.value} Children<br/>Of {!item.key} Region</h3></a>`

Comment: Please edit your post and type code there. Its highly unreadable in comments.

Comment: Does the rendering work if you remove one variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can replace & by

```
&amp;
```

to have :

```
<a aura:id="child321" href="{!'/apex/viewAllRegionsVerticalHierarchyCR?id='+v.acco‌​untId1+'&amp;Region='+it‌​em.key}"> <h3>View all<br/>{!item.value} Children<br/>Of {!item.key} Region</h3></a>
```

This is the value to use in evaluable conditional expressions so maybe it's the same inside an expression string

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_operators.htm (Logical Operators paragraph)

Comment: Does it work ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an additional string attribute, compose it in the controller and inject it with a single `href="{!yourAttrName}"`

This will move the ampersand and it concatenation from markup to javascript and there it should work fine.

Comment: String constants work. E.g. <a href="{!'/' + v.value}">foo</a> is fine. This must be the case because lightning doesn't allow you to set part of an attribute value in an expression: <a href="/{!v.value}">foo</a> won't compile. The expression has to evaluate to the entire attribute value, so including string constants is a common pattern.

Comment: @RobertSussland I modified my answer. Still I think it might be a viable approach worth to try